# HTTP 'Delete' and 'POST' Request in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, httprequest

I have a couple of questions

1) How can we make make DELETE request to a restful api using MATLAB?
   Matlab has webread and webwrite functions but they only support GET 
   and POST request.

2) How can we make a POST request and display the HTTP response code in MATLAB? (I already tried urlread2 but it does not allow json in body to make the request so it does not help)
The problem here is that when i tried webwrite for a POST request then then it expects some content to be sent back in form of json/text/etc but i only need an HTTP response code like 200 Ok

```
data = loadjson('json.txt')
[output, extras] = urlread2(base_url,'POST',data,header)
```

this raises the error that 'Function input: body, should be of class char, uint8, or int8, detected: struct'

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add a [mcve] detailing the code you have tried. Explain why it does not work for you and what the expected results are.